# Holding reference of Lifecycle object in LifecycleObserver

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

In the LifecycleObserver class how good is it a practice to hold the reference of Lifecycle object? What complication can arise?

```
class MyLocationListener implements LifecycleObserver {
    private Lifecycle mLifecycle;
    public MyLocationListener(Context context, Lifecycle lifecycle, Callback callback) {
           mLifecycle = lifecycle  
           ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not keep a reference it is an opening for memory leaks the Observer needs to observe not to contain the reference and if you want to perform actions on lifecycle changes do it like so:

```
 @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY //you can change to whatever lifecycle event you need)
 public void activityDestroied() {
 //actions here
 }
```

Comment: Right, I was asking about a scenario where the observer need to access the state of lifecycle, in that case we need to keep the reference.

Comment: What scenario would that be needed

Comment: To check the state of lifecycleOwner using lifecycle.getState() before performing a function
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html

Comment: You don't need to you need to make sure you're handling your variables in the proper place and if you want to be extra careful just perform all of your actions in the lifecycle functions. I don't actually see a reason to hold one

Comment: If I want to get the STATE of a LifecycleOwner in LifeCycleObservers' method, how do you suggest to do that?

Comment: Create an enum with all of the lifecycle events and for every lifecycle change, change the enum as well

Comment: Isn't that exactly what Lifecycle object does? Shouldn't this depend on case to case basis rather avoiding LifecycleOwner reference at all? just trying to weigh the options.

Comment: No because lifecycle also contain a reference to an activity  with again is an opening for memory leak